# Valgrind indicates a memory leak

Tags: c, memory, valgrind

So, I have some code and Valgrind seems to indicate that there is a memory leak present but I am not seeing it.  The code in question is

```
void *run_client(void *n)
{

    char recv_buffer[1024];

    // This is random, but right now we will allocate 5120 bytes
    // for the data coming from the instrument.
    const int data_size = 5120;
    int numbytes;

    struct net_info *n_info;
    n_info = (struct net_info *)malloc(sizeof(struct net_info));
    n_info = (struct net_info *)n;

    int clientfd;
    clientfd = init_client(&n_info->cfg);

    while (!*(n_info->flag))
    {
        // Clear the buffer every time...
        memset(recv_buffer, 0, 1024);
        if ((numbytes = recv(clientfd, recv_buffer, data_size - 1, 0)) == -1)
        {
            perror("recv");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (recv_buffer[0] != '{' || recv_buffer[numbytes - 1] != '\n')
            continue;

        // remove last two bytes that are EOL indicators
        numbytes -= 2;
        recv_buffer[numbytes] = 0;

        wclear(n_info->packet_win);
        box(n_info->packet_win, 0, 0);

        mvwprintw(n_info->packet_win, 1, 1, "%s", recv_buffer);
        wrefresh(n_info->packet_win);
    }

    close(clientfd);
    free(n_info);
    return 0;
}
```

I am not sure if the details are necessary, but they are provided here so that you can understand the context.  The function above  is called from `pthread_create` and listens on a specified port for data.  The string data is then posted to an ncurses window (the code is preliminary and is currently just used for testing).  The function exits when the main loop receives a request to exit and the flag in the while loop is set high.

The message from Valgrind is

```
==24037== 88 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 14 of 55
==24037==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==24037==    by 0x401897: run_client (ncurses-cpc.c:60)
==24037==    by 0x52906DA: start_thread (pthread_create.c:463)
==24037==    by 0x57D588E: clone (clone.S:95)
```

and line 60 refers to `n_info = (struct net_info *)malloc(sizeof(struct net_info));`.  As you can see, before exiting the function requests a `free` of the memory associated with that struct before exiting.  Am I missing something?  Why is Valgrind flagging this? (the message is posted *after* the heap summary message when valgrind is run with the option `leak-check=yes`.)

Comment: Why are you allocating memory? You're dropping the pointer to it in the line right after allocating.

Comment: You `malloc` n_info then immediately re-assign it. The mem from the `malloc` is lost.

Comment: what's the purpose of this `n_info = (struct net_info *)malloc(sizeof(struct net_info));` if you over write `n_info` in immediate next statement like `n_info = (struct net_info *)n;` ?

Comment: OK...thanks for pointing out this problem.  So, keeping in mind that this is a function called by `pthread_create` and passed the variable `n`, would it be correct to have the statement `struct net_info *n_info = n;` and then let the main loop release the memory associated with the input?

Comment: If main thread does `malloc`, it is usual to have main do the `free`. But, _if_ the struct is _not_ used to pass back data to main at the end, then child thread _may_ do the `free` at the bottom. Otherwise, after doing `pthread_join`, main may examine the struct and then `free` it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments it appears that you want to pass the input struct to the client thread. 
The leak appears because you allocate some memory and immediately discard the pointer to it.

No, you cannot just do -

```
struct net_info *n_info = n;
```

and `free` the memory from the main loop, because that would lead to use after free bug.

What you need to do is transfer the ownership of this buffer to the thread. This basically means that from the point the thread starts, the input buffer is owned by the thread and it is the thread's responsibility to `free` it.

You need to remove the new `malloc` in the thread and just use the pointer directly. The pointer will be `free`'d after the thread is done using it.

Also be careful that the main loop (or any other thread) should not be sharing the same buffer. This means that the main loop should `malloc` a separate buffer for every thread it creates.

Comment: **because that would lead to use after free bug** This would only be the case if the main loop exited *before* the thread, correct?  I call `pthread_join` in the main loop to wait for the completion of this loop.  **What you need to do is transfer the ownership of this buffer to the thread.**  No - this structure is used for communication between the main loop and this thread, so this is not what I want to do.

Comment: @cirrusio I assume you are creating a lot of threads. Probably one for every client. In that case the main would have to save all the pointers (probably in some array) and then free it if you want to do it after `pthread_join`. Regarding the ownership, the struct can still be used by main for communication even if the ownership is with the thread. Ownership simply means who manages the buffer. Any thread can read write to it. Keeping the free (and the owner ship) with the thread makes it easy for you to track the buffers for each thread and get free'd as the thread is done using it.

Comment: You probably do not want to delay the freeing untill __all__ the threads are done.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  This *is* the client, not the server (hence the name `run_client`) and so there is only one thread associated with this function. **Keeping the free (and the owner ship) with the thread makes it easy for you to track the buffers** OK, this makes a lot of sense.  So, going  back to the original code, this would still be something like `struct net_info *n_info = n` correct?  And then at the close of the function I would `free(n_info)`?

Comment: @cirrusio yes, that would be the correct way. Don't use malloc inside the thread. Just call free at the end (assuming malloc was called in the main loop).

Comment: Thanks, that looked manky to me anyway.  Will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

```
n_info = (struct net_info *)malloc(sizeof(struct net_info));
```

You just allocated memory... and the very next line:

```
n_info = (struct net_info *)n;
```

You overwrite `n_info` with `n`, losing the reference to the memory you just allocated. The `free()` by the end of the function is actually freeing `n`, not the memory this `malloc()` allocated.